# Joining a domain with kali

Tags: linux, windows-domain, kali-linux

I'm in school and I was asked if I could join a domain with Kali.

Everywhere I search says use "likewise open" but I've went into "add/remove programs" and searched for "likewise open" but it has no results.

I've also searched how to join kali to a domain and they all say get "likewise open"

Comment: Likewise Open is the route to go, but keep in mind the name of the software has changed. It's now under the name PowerBroker Open.